# how to display model name in different languages in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localization, migration

i have a model called employees whiche has a name in latin and arabic, so i used in my migration this:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('picture');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('name_ar');
            $table->string('name_fr');
            $table->string('position');
            $table->string('position_ar');
            $table->string('position_fr');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And i want to display the correct name in the language depending on the localization, for example if the localization is `'fr'` i should display `name_fr` or `name_ar` for `'ar'`,
i am using a [localization package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization).

for now i came up with this:

```
@if (Lang::locale() == 'ar')

            <h4 class="text-white"> {{ $employee->name_ar }} </h4>
            <div class="flex items-center gap-x-1">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/eye-icon.svg') }}" alt="eye">
                <p class="text-white text-sm">{{ $employee->position_ar }}</p>
            </div>

        @elseif(Lang::locale() == 'fr')

            <h4 class="text-white"> {{ $employee->name_fr }} </h4>
            <div class="flex items-center gap-x-1">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/eye-icon.svg') }}" alt="eye">
                <p class="text-white text-sm">{{ $employee->position_fr }}</p>
            </div>

        @else

            <h4 class="text-white"> {{ $employee->name }} </h4>
            <div class="flex items-center gap-x-1">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/eye-icon.svg') }}" alt="eye">
                <p class="text-white text-sm">{{ $employee->position }}</p>
            </div>

@endif
```

is there a better way to display the name in the correct language, for example in a controller or in the Lang directory ?.

Comment: Laravel admit string localization which may be usefull for labels and system messages, you can have a look here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization

Comment: The way you have now is functional, but the package you're using is for Laravel translations (i.e. things found in `resources/lang/{locale}` folder(s)), not model translations. https://github.com/Astrotomic/laravel-translatable or https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable are the common packages for handling this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could achieve that with a one-line like this

```
{{ $employee->{'name_' . app()->getLocale()} ?? $employee->name }}
```

thanks to @Tim Lewis for mentioning it.

Comment: in the migration if you check after the `name` it's `name_ar` and `name_fr` and also in blade he is should transated name not the name column

Comment: Also, `$employee[name_.Lang::locale()]` is a syntax error; `name_` is not defined, `.` is an unexpected token, etc. Correct syntax would be `{{ $employee->{'name_' . app()->locale()} }}` (or similar)

Comment: I have updated my Answer now it should work

Comment: `{locale}` will bring `ar` or `fr` then the name will become like this `name_ar` or `name_fr` this way he could use like this in the blade `{{$employee->name}}

Comment: This is what i did, in inspiration of your solution   @MohammadEdrisRaufi : 
```{{ $employee->{Lang::locale() == 'en' ? 'name' : 'name_' . Lang::locale()} }}```

Comment: don't do that check for the key availability because if in the future if you had an other language than your code will break use the answer it will check if the key is available it will show otherwise it will show only the name